# How to integrate editable Google drive in a PHP website?

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api, drive, file-sharing

So I have a PHP website and I want to create a platform where managers can upload some files and staff can later access and edit them..

I have created a separate login system for both parties, the last step would be to implement appropriate solution for described file sharing..

Im thinking about embedded Google Drive, I already tried this:

`<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>`

The problem is, with this iframe code I get just the view of files... Is there a way I can embedded Google Drive so I can edit the structure in it (add files and folders, rename, delete them, etc) without leaving my php site?

Or maybe someone knows better alternatives for achieving this functionality?

Comment: as @ziganotschka just added, you should look into the Google Drive API which would let you interact with Google Drive from your webserver: https://developers.google.com/drive/

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of APIs for Google Drive API which can be found in https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/drive/v3/. API integration would be a better option than using iframes. I hope this is helpful.